# NullPointerException java

Tags: java, android, массивы

Приветствую, друзья! Возникла странная ситуация, с которой пытаюсь бороться уже пару дней. Есть массив объектов класса Bot (класс самописный) и код типа такого:

```
private int getBotNumber(int x, int y) {
    int result;
    for(result = 0; result < 1750; result++) {
        if(bot[result] != null && bot[result].getX() == x && bot[result] == y) {
            if (bot[result] == null)
                System.out.println("null"); //точка останова 1
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bot[result] == null)
        System.out.println("null"); //точка останова 2
    return result;
}
```

Во время отладки срабатывает только точка останова №2. Вопрос: почему не срабатывает первая? Спасибо!

---

Всем спасибо! Вопрос решил. Ошибка крылась в другой части кода.

Comment: Правильно не может быть одновременно null и не null. Но после цикла он снова проверяется, и тогда он уже null. Как так?

Comment: `if(bot[result] != null) {
            if (bot[result] == null) ` что?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if(bot[result] != null && ...) {
>     if (bot[result] == null)
> ```

Ну и как же ему одновременно не быть null'ом и быть им?